# Why does PowerShell 5 from Windows 7 not have the same features as Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, windows-console, powershell-5.0, psreadline

I upgraded my PowerShell from 4.0 to 5.0 (Feb. 2016 release) on my Windows 7 SP1 machine.

The `$PSVersionTable` shows PowerShell 5.0, but the shell does not have the same features as PowerShell 5.0 in Windows 10.

Differences:

- Keyword highlighting
- Text selection with Shift+Arrow keys
- Copy/paste with Ctrl+C/V

Why is there a difference?

How to get/enable these missing features?

Comment: Install/Import [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) to get the visual editing features you see in Win10 (where PSReadLine is included by default)

Comment: Frode's answer is more complete

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some features come from the [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine)-module that is preinstalled in Win10. You can install this manually from github or by running:

```
Install-Module PSReadLine
```

Some features come from Windows 10-enhancements to the console host `conhost.exe` that is used by default for powershell and cmd. `conhost.exe`is a part of windows itself and not Windows Management Framework which Powershell is a part of.